# Androidの暗号化と鍵の管理について教えて下さい。

Tags: android, security

Androidでデータの暗号化と鍵の管理を行うには、Android Keystore Systemを使用するようにデベロッパーページなど記載されていますが、このキー管理はFactoryResetで消えてしまうようです。FactoryResetで消えずにセキュアな鍵の保持方法はないでしょうか？申し訳ないですがご教授下さい。

Comment: 初期化で消えるのは理由も根拠もあるのでこの挙動を変えることは今後もないでしょう。もしかしたら XY 問題かも？「消えない鍵」が必要な理由を説明すると別の案がつくかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。デバイスの証明書などを暗号化して初期状態から持っておきたいと思っています

Answer (score 0):

androidのKeystoreは、ユーザー操作によりkeyが消える事を前提に使用する必要があります。
[こちら](https://www.slideshare.net/ak_shio_555/droid-kaigi2018)にDroid kaigiの発表資料でまとめてあるものがありましたので、ご参照ください。

アプリ初期状態から暗号化したい場合、アプリ起動時に一度復号してみて、
失敗したら新規デバイスとして再度データを暗号化し直すのはいかがでしょうか